# Is Oauth2 more trouble than it's worth due to the issues of account duplication?

Tags: sql, database, oauth, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I've recognized with Oauth2 that users are continuously being confused because they sign up with Facebook, then when they return to the site and forget which social media platform they clicked, they make a new account and believe their old account was deleted!

I realize there are some preventatives that can be taken, but that's not always the case. Would it be better to only offer email/password to avoid these issues, especially for websites where the user's data is critical (games, courses, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no magic wand for the users who has forgotten what oauth provider the user has used for the site to register. This is especially a problem when the site offers multiple oauth ways. There are few ways to reduce the duplicacy.

1. Auto sign-in if the user is already signed in to the provider. Most oauth provider support this via auth cookies.
2. Have an extra logic written inside your site to merge accounts or recognize mail address. Most users use the same mail id for facebook, google or msa.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have to look into option 1, I don't have much experience with authentication/cookies, but I'm willing to learn